# How do I send the UserManager to the business layer in ASP.NET CORE with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

In WebUI, I can access UserManager via Controller. However, I cannot reach through the business layer.
When I try to access it from the business layer, I get an error like the one below.

[image: NullReferenceException]

### My Busines Layer

#### UserRepository

```cs
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public UserRepository(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IResult> Create(AppUser appUser)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser);

        if (result.Succeeded == false)
        {
            return new ErrorResult();
        }

        return new SuccessResult();
    }

}
```

#### UserService

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IDataResult<UserForSignUpDto>> SignUp(UserForSignUpDto userForSignUpDto)
    {
        AppUser user = new AppUser
        {
            UserName = userForSignUpDto.UserName,
            Email = userForSignUpDto.Email,
        };

        IResult result = await _userRepository.Create(user);

        if (result.Success == false)
        {
            return new ErrorDataResult<UserForSignUpDto>(userForSignUpDto, IdentityMessages.UserSignUpError);
        }

        return new SuccessDataResult<UserForSignUpDto>(userForSignUpDto, IdentityMessages.UserSignUpSuccess);
    }
}
```

### My WebUI Layer

#### My WebUI Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public HomeController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        UserForSignUpDto userForSignUpDto = new UserForSignUpDto
        {
            UserName = "test1",
            Email = "test1@gmail.com",
            Password = "test"
        };

        _userService.SignUp(userForSignUpDto);

        return View();
    }
}
```

#### My Startup's ConfigureService

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AnonymContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLProvider"), y => y.MigrationsAssembly("Anonym.DataAccess")));

    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLProvider"), y => y.MigrationsAssembly("Anonym.DataAccess")));

    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
        {
            //options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";

            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    services.AddTransient<AppIdentityDbContext>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Comment: A DbSet is already a repository, a DbContext is already a Unit-Of-Work. And UserManager is a *service* that uses its own repository. Right now you've ended up with an anemic service on top of an anemic repository on top of the actual service that uses its own repository. The BLL ended up containing data and service classes, nothing specific to the business at hand

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why not use the UserManage directly, assuming you really need to do that? Signing up should be the responsibility of a different controller for example, not the home screen's. You can compose controllers and views if you want to display different web parts/widgets on the home screen but the *home* controller shouldn't have to know about logging in or signing up

Comment: I used it for testing purposes only on the Home screen. My goal is to manage UserManager and Identity objects from the business layer. I will only send the data to be processed with the controller. All other transactions should be managed from the business layer.

Comment: ASP.NET Core already contains an entire subsystem [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with pages that can be used as-is or scaffolded and modified. You should check how they work. In any case, there's no reason to put a repo and thin service on top of another service before using it. Just because layering is good doesn't mean everything has to be named `Repository`. Especially when it's *not* about data access

Comment: Specifically, [check how the built-in registration page works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-register-login-logout-and-registerconfirmation) as you'll have to use the same code.

Comment: I can use the Identity classes on the controller. My goal is not to write Identity codes again when I include a WepApi or other presentation layer in a project. Only the data to be processed will be sent from the presentation layers. The business layer will process this data. I try to improve myself in software architecture. Are these approaches wrong?